# Wait for Display.getDefault.asyncexec

Tags: asynchronous, eclipse-plugin, thread-safety

I am trying to use Display.getDefault().asyncExec to execute some work i need to do on my eclipse plugin but i need to wait until this work is done.
I cannot wait for the thread without pausing the UI. How do i wait for Display?

Comment: asyncExec does not run a thread, it executes a piece of code in the existing User Interface thread. There is no standard way to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use Display.getDefault().asyncExec to execute some work i need to do on my eclipse plugin but i need to wait until this work is done

Either use `syncExec` instead, which will return when the work is done, or add a call to the code which needs to wait at the end of the `Runnable` you pass to `asyncExec`.